# I cannot protect my path using a file called ProtectedRoutes in React V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-router

I am trying to protect my path /Auth, but there is a problem with my file ProtectedRoutes. Could someone assist me in discovery what do I need to change? I am sure it is related with the change of React V5 to V6 but my research just let me more confuse. Thank you

This is my code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>  
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Account from "./Account";
import FreeComponent from "./FreeComponent";
import AuthComponent from "./AuthComponent";
import ProtectedRoutes from "./ProtectedRoutes";


function App() {
  return (

    <Container>
    <Row>
        <Col className="text-center">
          <h1>React Authentication Tutorial</h1>

          <section id="navigation">
            <a href="/">Home </a>
            <a href="/free">Free Component </a>
            <a href="/auth">Auth Component </a>
          </section>
        </Col>
      </Row>

         {/* create routes here */}
      <Routes>
       <Route exact path="/" element={
       <Account />} />
       <Route exact path="/free" element={
         <FreeComponent />} />
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
         <Route exact path="/auth" element={<AuthComponent/>}/>
      </Route>
     </Routes>

    </Container>

  );
}

export default App;
```

ProtectedRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Navigate, Outlet} from 'react-router-dom';
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();


    const useAuth=()=>{
    const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");
      if(token){
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }

    const  ProtectedRoutes=(props:any) =>{
      const auth=useAuth()

      return auth?<Outlet/>: <Navigate to="/"/>
    }

    export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

AuthComponent.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();

// get token generated on login
const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");

export default function AuthComponent() {
  // set an initial state for the message we will receive after the API call
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  // useEffect automatically executes once the page is fully loaded
  useEffect(() => {
    // set configurations for the API call here
    const configuration = {
      method: "get",
      url: "https://myurl.com/auth-endpoint",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };

    // make the API call
    axios(configuration)
      .then((result) => {
        // assign the message in our result to the message we initialized above
        setMessage(result.data.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        error = new Error();
      });
  }, []);

  // logout
  const logout = () => {
    // destroy the cookie
    cookies.remove("TOKEN", { path: "/" });
    // redirect user to the landing page
    window.location.href = "/";
  }

  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      <h1>Auth Component</h1>

      {/* displaying our message from our API call */}
      <h3 className="text-danger">{message}</h3>

      {/* logout */}
      <Button type="submit" variant="danger" onClick={() => logout()}>
        Logout
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The issue is that when I access http://localhost:3000/auth I can see the page without the need of logging in. I am trying to protect this path so users need to login first.

Comment: Seems the `useAuth` hook is returning true when it shouldn't. Had you previously logged in and accessed `"/auth"` then logged out and could still access `"/auth"`? I don't think `useAuth` is being rerendered to pick up cookie changes, ***or*** the cookie isn't cleared out as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a little change in your App.js:

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<Account />} />
  <Route exact path="/free" element={<FreeComponent />} />
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoute Component={AuthComponent} />} exact path="/auth"/>
</Routes>;
```

and get the Component in your ProtectedRoute like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();


    const useAuth=()=>{
    const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");
      if(token){
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }

    const  ProtectedRoutes=(Component) =>{
      const auth=useAuth()

      return auth?<Component/>: <Navigate to="/"/>
    }

    export default ProtectedRoutes;
```